# How to use spring mvc controller make a post request?

Tags: spring-mvc, post

How to make a controller method to redirect to other site with a post request?

```
    @RequestMapping("/link)
    public RedirectView  goToTheSite(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("name", "wow");
        return new RedirectView("https://www.thesite.com", true, false, false);

    }
```

but, this is not working, 
How to do that in right way?

Answer (score 3):

> How to make a controller method to redirect to other site with a post
>   request?

Redirect means you telling browser to make a GET request, There is no out of the box feature in Spring MVC to make POST request from controller.

> How to do that in right way?

Use [Apache HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html):

```
Request.Post("https://www.thesite.com/login")
    .bodyForm(Form.form().add("username",  "vip").add("password",  "secret").build())
    .execute().returnContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to send a POST is to send a populated HTML form to the browser, with the action parameter pointing to the new site and method="POST".

```
<form name="myform" action="https://www.thesite.com" method="post">
     <input name="name" type="hidden" value="true" />
     <input name="phone" type="hidden" value="false" />
     <input name="phone" type="hidden" value="false" />
     <noscript>
         <input type="submit" value="Click here to continue" />
     </noscript>
</form>
```

Then Add javascript to automatically submit the form :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.myform.submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this can work, but for security reason I want this post request is made in server side.Can spring mvc can do that?

Comment: @user2802211 did you do it?I have same requirement.. :(